# 1001 Spikes level 10-4: Tricky jump strategy

Tags: 1001-spikes

About midway into the level 10-4, there is a single-block of ice you need to land on, and to do it, you have to jump over a single-block of spikes just in front of it.

My problem is that even when I manage to execute the exact same jumps, the results are erratic. Sometimes it works, sometimes just doesn't.

I have tried some alternative methods many times(jumping from 1, 2, 3, and 4 pixels away from the leftmost pixel of the spikes while standing or running) but none seems to have a consistent result.

I think the jump mechanics there are similar to trying to jump over a **single-block** of spikes with the **low-jump**, and that if there is a consistent way to do one, it will also work for the other. But of course, I haven't found a way do that **consistently** either.

So my question is: Has anyone found a **consistent** method to make either of those jumps? By "consistent", I mean that the method works **every time** you manage to execute it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually been struggling with this level a moment ago, which quickly went from "this puzzley level is my favorite in the game" to "this is the worst level ever". But I digress.

I haven't had the time to develop muscle memory for this jump because I got lucky, but the few attempts when I had an actual strategy I had most luck with this setup:

[image: 1001 Spikes tricky jump positioning]

The left foot should be standing almost exactly one tile away from the spikes.

Please note that the actual screen is from a different location in the same stage, but the idea stays the same. It might also be that you have to be one pixel to the right, I am not 100% certain if I am pressing the two keys at the same frame.

Comment: Assuming the capture you provided is correct, I think you rather meant "leftmost foot should be standing one pixel off from the right edge **of the block to the left** of spike block. " However, I haven't tried your solution, as I've had enough of that game. :-) That level cost me 600+ lives, and a precious part of my *actual* life.

Comment: @Kemal By *spike block* I meant all the tiles which have spikes popping up out of them, not the tile containing the spikes but I agree the wording is awful, let me fix it.